# How do I set a background image in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, background-image

How do I set a background image using CSS and HTML that will work in Chrome? The following code works in IE, but not Chrome?

```
body 
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: URL("\Backgrounds\bg.jpg");
}
```

Comment: :Works well for me :[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/2aVpD/4/)

Answer (score 1):

this code works!!

```
body {
        background: url("../img/img_bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace backslash to forward slash in background-image path

So Code is

```
body 
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: URL("/Backgrounds/bg.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used backslashes in your URL instead of forward slashes. This isn't valid for URLs, so Chrome won't find it. However, IE is related to the File Explorer (in some versions of Windows, they were the same thing), so it will interpret a file path as you have it. Using a properly formatted URL will ensure the image file can be found on all browsers.

```
body 
   {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: URL("/Backgrounds/bg.jpg");
   }
```